# Azure Marketplace Fulfillment API throws Error 403 (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-marketplace

I try to integrate with **Azure Marketplace**. As a first step I try to implement [Resolve API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/partner-center-portal/pc-saas-fulfillment-api-v2#resolve-a-purchased-subscription) request.

I used a [commercial-marketplace-client-dotnet](https://github.com/Azure/commercial-marketplace-client-dotnet) GitHub repository as an example.

Our solution uses `.NET Framework` stack and I implemented some changes in the GitHub sources.
I have migrated class `ClientSecretTokenProvider` from `.NET Core` to `.NET Framework`.

My implementation of `ClientSecretTokenProvider` is here:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CloudMonix.Infrastructure.AzureMarketplace
{
    public class ClientSecretTokenProvider : ITokenProvider
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/partner-center-portal/pc-saas-registration#get-a-token-based-on-the-azure-ad-app

        private const string AuthenticationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token";
        private const string MarketplaceResourceId = "20e940b3-4c77-4b0b-9a53-9e16a1b010a7";

        private readonly string _tenantId;
        private readonly string _clientId;
        private readonly string _clientSecret;

        public ClientSecretTokenProvider(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            _tenantId = tenantId;
            _clientId = clientId;
            _clientSecret = clientSecret;
        }

        public Task<AuthenticationHeaderValue> GetAuthenticationHeaderAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var credential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret);

            var authority = string.Format(AuthenticationEndpoint, _tenantId);
            var scope = $"{MarketplaceResourceId}/.default";

            var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var token = context.AcquireToken(scope, credential);

            var result = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);

            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

All other classes (auto-generated client and models) I have added to our solution without any changes.

Also I have registered new Azure Application (and generate Client Secret Key). I provided **Application ID** and **Tennant ID** to my offer:
[image]

I can receive Azure Marketplace Token from the Landing Page request GET parameter.
Also I can successfully get **AccessToken** using `ClientSecretTokenProvider` class.

But when I use **AccessToken** to the Fulfillment API ([Resolve API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/partner-center-portal/pc-saas-fulfillment-api-v2#resolve-a-purchased-subscription) request) then I got **Error 403**.

What I'm missing?

Thanks to advance to any help.

***UPDATE 1:***

Example of usage `MarketplaceSaaSClient` class:

```
public ActionResult Index(string token)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        var tenantId = "<TENANT ID>";
        var clientId = "<APP ID>";
        var clientSecret = "<APP SECRET>";

        var requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var client = new MarketplaceSaaSClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var subscription = client.FulfillmentOperations.Resolve(token, requestId, correlationId);
    }

    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

    return View();
}
```

Comment: There are two likely possibilities 1) The version of TLS (used for authentication) you are using is wrong 2) The encryption mode in the certificate isn't supported in the TLS version you are using.  I would use a sniffer and verify that TLS 1.2/1.3 is being used.  TLS 1.0/1.1 is no longer supported and cannot be used.  It doesn't look like the GITHUB code sets the TLS version so you are using the default version on your machine.  Where is your client code?

Comment: @jdweng Thank you. I have added example of usage MarketplaceSaaSClient. Also I have added TLS version 1.2 support. Unfortunately I see error in the response. I think I have trouble with Azure Application. For me is strange why I do not add any permissions to the App? Microsoft documentation says nothing about permissions.

Comment: The certificate is loaded in both the user and machine certificate stores.  So if the user doesn't have the certificate in the stores the connection will fail.  The server also has Roles that allow user groups to connect and the Role may have issues.  You should also verify the encryption mode on the certificate is allowed with TLS 1.2.  You may need TLS 1.3.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security